# iPads with same OS but keys in different locations

Tags: keyboard, ipad, ipados

I have a new iPad Mini 6, and and old iPad Air 2.  Both are running iOS 15.5.  On both, I have two software keyboard's configured: English (US)/QWERTY, and Greek.

On each iPad, when the keyboard comes up, there is a little key with a globe icon in the lower left.  This toggles between the English and Greek keyboards.  I'll call this the "alphabet" key.

There is also a key for switching to numbers and extra punctuation.  I'll call this the "number" key.

The problem is that these keys are not in the same place on the two iPads. Their locations are reversed:

- On the  iPad Air 2, the alphabet key is to the right of the number key, and the number key is labeled ".?123".
- On the iPad Mini 6, the alphabet key is to the left of the number key, which is labeled "123".

I don't care about the label on the number key, but the fact that the two keys are in reverse order is a problem, because I often type mathematical expressions that include Greek letters.  I'll never get used to either configuration.

I've gone into the keyboard configuration in General in Settings, and have experimented a little bit, but I don't see anything that would affect the location of the number and globe keys.  The configurations on the two iPads are the same as far as I can see.  I tried deleting and re-adding the English and Greek keyboards, but that didn't seem to change anything.  It seems very strange that keys would be in different locations because of different hardware; the keyboards are in software.

Maybe the iPad Air 2 has an old version of the English (US) keyboard, and the Mini 6 has a new version, but I don't know how to make one use the keyboard version of the other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Different sized iPads do have somewhat different screen keyboards, and I don't think there is any way to make them the same, except possibly by using a 3rd party keyboard app like Keyman.

Comment: Thanks @TomGewecke.  This doesn't seem like a size issue to me, but maybe that's it.   Swapping the two keys shouldn't have to change the keyboard space; the keys take up the same screen space whichever order they're in, and key sizes shrink or expand when the keyboard is split or merged.   I also have an old iPad MIni 2 which can't run anything later than iOS 12.  That's got the same keyboard as the iPad Air 2 running iOS 15.5.  But the Mini 2 is just a little bit wider than the Mini 6, so maybe that's the difference.  If that's it, it would be weird--but not be the first time for Apple.